# textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: in subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates, uitextfield

I've subclassed a UITextField and I'd like to use a method similar to `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` inside the subclass to get notified when a character is typed and if necessary block the change, but avoid setting the fields delegate to itself.

I've found if I override `keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:` and `keyboardInputShouldDelete:` I can get the desired effect, unfortunately these methods are private and anything using the class won't make it through the App Store submission process.

Anyone know of a public method that achieves the same thing and doesn't require the field being its own delegate?

**UPDATE:**

I went with the suggestion of creating a separate object just to be the delegate, which itself can have a delegate to forward messages to.

Comment: Can you clarify? It's not immediately clear why you wouldn't use textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:, i.e. get the subclass to set its instances as their own delegates.

Comment: The only problem with setting it as its own delegate is forwarding events to an actual delegate that might want to respond to UITextField events. Currently, I'm using addTarget:action:forControlEvent: to respond to those events internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having tried to subclass UITextField before, I've since learned to avoid that and go the delegate route instead (it has a similar method called `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` that should do what I think you've described).

Comment: Sure, but that's only available if I set the textfield to be its own delegate, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I don't like to make the UITextField its own delegate either - I usually use my own `ScottTextFieldValidator` subclass as the class of the delegate (which has all the methods/state it needs). There's no reason the UITextField itself has to be its own delegate.

Comment: Yeah I'm leaning toward this approach as well.

Comment: @Scott +1 for reinforcing the virtues of delegation. I've updated my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

One strategy to explore here is to override the setDelegate: method and then do some message forwarding. You can use `[super setDelegate: self]` to make sure your calls gets first dibs at the delegate messages. In your override of setDelegate: set an internal ivar, e.g.

```
 - (void) setDelegate: (id<UITextFieldDelegate>) internalDelegate;
 {
     [setInternalDelegate: internalDelegate];
 }
```

Then for each of the the UITextField delegate methods do your thing before forwarding on the delegate message, e.g.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
{
      // do your thing with range and replacement string

      // now forward message on the 'other' delegate    
       [[self internalDelegate] textField: self shouldChangeCharactersInRange: range replacementString: string];
}
```

Typically, you'll want to override all of the delegate methods, even if for most of them all you do is a straight forward.

**Update** You note in comments that the forwarding approach is raising issues. If so, then traditional delegation is the way to go. (And, in generally, it *is* the way to go - although I've used forwarding delegate once or twice, I'm not sure if, with hindsight, it was absolutely essential and I've not checked to see if I've done it with UITextField. @[Scott Corscadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297472/scott-corscadden) has and does not recommend it.)

The most common pattern is to make the ViewController that looks after the view in which the `UITextField` is a subview the delegate. You don't say in your answer if there's particular reason why you need to work with the subclass. If you're packing interesting stuff into the `UITextField` then it might be, though you could always another poster suggests and create a companion class for `UITextField` that does that work and use that as the delegate.  In any case, if need be, you can always get the delegate object to call extra methods on your `UITextField` subclass, e.g.

```
// in the delegate object class

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
{
      [delegate doSomeExtraThingInTheTextFieldSubclassThatItSeemsToMakeSenseToDoThereRatherThanHere];

      // maybe that's it, or maybe this object also wants to do something here...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can forward them without having to implement? So only the methods my subclass implements are called on it, but everything else is passed along to the next delegate?

Comment: I don't think so. But it only takes five mins to implement the forwarding for the 7 messages in the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. Given that it's UI and people are slow compared to message sending, the overhead is irrelevant.

Comment: I've also found setting either using [self setDelegate:self] or [super setDelegate:self] results in Xcode handing shortly after the simulator launches and then it requires a force quit. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like it's stuck in a loop calling keyboardInputChangedSelection:

Comment: I would strongly recommend to never ever set a delegate to self. Very easy to get into recursive loops, as the class tries to determine whether to send the message to the delegate might call a pre-existing UITextField method. Really recommend using your own subclass that you want to be the delegate, dump the 7 methods in there and bang - you have an uncle named Bob.

Answer (score 1):

You may play with Objective-C runtime to achieve this. The following code is working for me. 
The idea is:

- in subclass we set `delegate` property to self;
- we override `setDelegate:` method in which we store supplied delegate to a variable (`forwardDelegate`);
- by overriding `respondsToSelector:`, `forwardInvocation:` and `methodSignatureForSelector:` we either call method on self or forward it to saved `forwardDelegate`.

---

```
// MyTextField.h
@interface MyTextField : UITextField
@end

// MyTextField.m
@interface MyTextField () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyTextField {
    id forwardDelegate;
}

- (void) myTextFieldCommonInit
{
    [super setDelegate:self];
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        [self myTextFieldCommonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        [self myTextFieldCommonInit];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) setDelegate:(id)delegate
{
    forwardDelegate = delegate;
}

- (BOOL) respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [forwardDelegate respondsToSelector:selector];
    }
}

- (void) forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:[invocation selector]]) {
        [super forwardInvocation:invocation];
    } else if ([forwardDelegate respondsToSelector:[invocation selector]]) {
        [invocation invokeWithTarget:forwardDelegate];
    } else {
        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:[invocation selector]];
    }
}

- (NSMethodSignature *) methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (signature) {
        return signature;
    } else {
        return [forwardDelegate methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    ...
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate method of the uitextfield,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{

}
```

And don't forget to set your `textfield.delegate = self` in ViewDidLoad.